# ActionController::UrlGenerationError - with route defined and action in controller, still getting error for no route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting the following error in RSpec when running my schools_controller_spec.rb test:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schools"}
```

What's puzzling me is that I have the routes configured, and the action defined in the appropriate controller. I'm not getting this error for other tests in the spec, such as `'GET #index'`, etc. Running Rails 4.2 with RSpec/Capybara.

Here's the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home', id: 'home'
  resources :users
  resources :schools
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  match '/home',      to: 'pages#home', via: 'get', as: 'home_page'
end
```

rake routes returns:

```
    schools GET    /schools(.:format)          schools#index
            POST   /schools(.:format)          schools#create
 new_school GET    /schools/new(.:format)      schools#new
edit_school GET    /schools/:id/edit(.:format) schools#edit
     school GET    /schools/:id(.:format)      schools#show
            PATCH  /schools/:id(.:format)      schools#update
            PUT    /schools/:id(.:format)      schools#update
            DELETE /schools/:id(.:format)      schools#destroy
```

There's the route defined on the fifth line, as schools#show.

The schools_controller.rb:

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_signin
  before_filter :admin_only, except: :index, :show

  def index
    @schools = School.all
  end

  def show
   # code pending
  end

  private

    def admin_only
      unless current_user.admin?
        redirect_to :back, alert: "Access denied."
      end
    end
end
```

The link to the individual school seems to be properly defined in the view helper (_school.html.haml):

```
%li#schools
  = link_to school.name, school
  = school.short_name
  = school.city
  = school.state
```

and looking at the front-end HTML confirms it's working correctly. I can see, for example: `<a href="/schools/1">Community College of the Air Force</a>`. When I click that link the page shows the following in the debug dump:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
controller: schools
action: show
id: '1'
```

Finally, for good measure, here's the spec file (schools_controller_spec.rb):

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SchoolsController, type: :controller do
  # specs omitted for other actions

  describe 'GET #show' do
    context "when not signed in" do
      it "returns a 302 redirect code" do
        get :show
        expect(response.status).to eq 302
      end

      it "redirects to the signin page" do
        get :show
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_session_path
      end
    end

    context "when signed in as user" do
      before :each do
        @user = double(:user)
        allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return @user
        @school = create(:school)
      end

      it "assigns the school to the @school variable" do
        get :show
        expect(assigns(:school)).to eq @school
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The route appears in rake routes. The method is defined in the appropriate controller. There don't appear to be any silly naming errors (e.g. plural/singular). The spec doesn't appear to have any issues routing GET #index or other routes for example. Everything works *exactly* as expected in the browser.

So why do I keep getting the "no route matches" error when I run my controller spec?

Comment: It's because the show action is expecting an id, which you aren't providing in your test.

Comment: dang! feeling foolish I didn't see that... Got caught up looking at the error message, which doesn't mention "id", and didn't think it through. Do you want to post it as a response instead of a comment so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: It is often the way! Pleased that was it though, now I'm not at work I wrote out an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the show action is expecting an id which you currently aren't passing. Replace:

```
get :show
```

With this:

```
get :show, id: school.id
```

The above assumes you have a school variable, perhaps a let in a before block?

```
let(:school) { create(:school) }
```